# Correct way to use UITableViewDataSource and Custom UITableViewCell Delegate

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

I'm working on moving the `UITableViewDataSource` outside of the `UITableViewController`. However I have some custom cells that have their own delegates, which then call on the `tableView` to reload.

I'm not sure what the correct way of handling this is. Here's what I have:

```
final class MyTableViewController: UITableViewController {
    
    lazy var myTableViewDataSource: MyTableViewDataSource = { MyTableViewDataSource(myProperty: MyProperty) }()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.dataSource = myTableViewDataSource
    }

}
```

Cell

```
 protocol MyTableViewCellDelegate: AnyObject {
    func doSomething(_ cell: MyTableViewCellDelegate, indexPath: IndexPath, text: String)
}


 final class MyTableViewCell: UITableViewCell, UITextFieldDelegate {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var packageSizeTextField: UITextField!
    
    weak var delegate: MyTableViewCellDelegate?
    
    var indexPath = IndexPath()
    
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
    }
    
    func configureCell() {
        // configureCell...
    }
    
    func textFieldDidChangeSelection(_ textField: UITextField) {
        print(#function)
        delegate?.doSomething(self, indexPath: indexPath, text: textField.text ?? "")
    }
}
```

DataSource

```
final class MyTableViewDataSource: NSObject, UITableViewDataSource {
    
    var myProperty: MyProperty!
    
    init(myProperty: MyProperty) {
        self.myProperty = myProperty
    }
    
    // ...
    
    func doSomething(_ cell: MyTableViewCell, indexPath: IndexPath, text: String) {
        // ...
        tableView.performBatchUpdates({
            tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
        }) 
// ERROR - tableView doesn't exist
    }
    
}
```

My question is, how do I gain access to the `tableView` that this class is providing the source for? Is it as simple as adding a reference to the tableView like this?

```
var tableView: UITableView
var myProperty: MyProperty!

init(myProperty: MyProperty, tableView: UITableView) {
            self.myProperty = myProperty
            self.tableView = tableView
        }
```

Comment: Usually, `UITableViewDatasource` methods have a `UITableView` as parameter. Why not passing it also as a parameter of the method?

Comment: @Larme Thats another solution I had thought of. Adding `var tableView: UITableView` as a property on the cell itself. - I'm just not sure what the best/most correct way of getting access to the tableView from `UITableViewCell` and it's delegate is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is to have your `MyTableViewController` conform to your `MyTableViewCellDelegate` and then set the controller as the delegate in `cellForRowAt` in your dataSource class.

However, you may be much better off using a closure.

Get rid of your `delegate` and `indexPath` properties in your cell, and add a closure property:

```
final class MyTableViewCell: UITableViewCell, UITextFieldDelegate {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var packageSizeTextField: UITextField!
    
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        configureCell()
    }
    func configureCell() {
        // configureCell...
        packageSizeTextField.delegate = self
    }
    
    var changeClosure: ((String, UITableViewCell)->())?
    
    func textFieldDidChangeSelection(_ textField: UITextField) {
        print(#function)
        changeClosure?(textField.text ?? "", self)
//      delegate?.doSomething(self, indexPath: indexPath, text: textField.text ?? "")
    }
}
```

Now, in your dataSource class, set the closure:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let c = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "mtvc", for: indexPath) as! MyTableViewCell
    c.packageSizeTextField.text = myData[indexPath.row]
    c.changeClosure = { [weak self, weak tableView] str, c in
        guard let self = self,
              let tableView = tableView,
              let pth = tableView.indexPath(for: c)
        else {
            return
        }
        // update our data
        self.myData[pth.row] = str
        // do something with the tableView
        //tableView.reloadData()
    }
    return c
}
```

Note that as you have your code written, the first tap in the textField will not appear to do anything, because `textFieldDidChangeSelection` will be called immediately.

---

**Edit**

Here's a complete example that can be run without any Storyboard connections.

The cell creates a label and a text field, arranging them in a vertical stack view.

Row Zero will have the text field hidden and its label text will be set to the concatenated strings from `myData`.

The rest of the rows will have the label hidden.

The closure will be called on `.editingChanged` (instead of `textFieldDidChangeSelection`) so it is not called when editing begins.

Also implements row deletion for demonstration purposes.

The first row will be reloaded when text is changed in any row's text field, and when a row is deleted.

**Cell Class**

```
final class MyTableViewCell: UITableViewCell, UITextFieldDelegate {
    
    var testLabel = UILabel()
    var packageSizeTextField = UITextField()

    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        configureCell()
    }
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        configureCell()
    }
    func configureCell() {
        // configureCell...
        let stack = UIStackView()
        stack.axis = .vertical
        stack.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        testLabel.numberOfLines = 0
        testLabel.backgroundColor = .yellow
        
        packageSizeTextField.borderStyle = .roundedRect
        
        stack.addArrangedSubview(testLabel)
        stack.addArrangedSubview(packageSizeTextField)
        
        contentView.addSubview(stack)
        
        let g = contentView.layoutMarginsGuide
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            stack.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor),
            stack.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor),
            stack.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor),
            stack.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.bottomAnchor),
        ])
        
        packageSizeTextField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(textChanged(_:)), for: .editingChanged)
    }
    
    var changeClosure: ((String, UITableViewCell)->())?
    
    @objc func textChanged(_ v: UITextField) -> Void {
        print(#function)
        changeClosure?(v.text ?? "", self)
    }
}
```

**TableView Controller Class**

```
class MyTableViewController: UITableViewController {
    
    lazy var myTableViewDataSource: MyTableViewDataSource = {
        MyTableViewDataSource()
    }()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = .systemBackground
        tableView.register(MyTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "mtvc")
        tableView.dataSource = myTableViewDataSource
    }

}
```

**TableView DataSource Class**

```
final class MyTableViewDataSource: NSObject, UITableViewDataSource {

    var myData: [String] = [
        " ",
        "One",
        "Two",
        "Three",
        "Four",
        "Five",
        "Six",
        "Seven",
        "Eight",
    ]

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if editingStyle == .delete {
            myData.remove(at: indexPath.row)
            tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
            tableView.reloadRows(at: [IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)], with: .automatic)
        } else if editingStyle == .insert {
            // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view.
        }
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
        return indexPath.row != 0
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return myData.count
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let c = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "mtvc", for: indexPath) as! MyTableViewCell
        c.testLabel.isHidden = indexPath.row != 0
        c.packageSizeTextField.isHidden = indexPath.row == 0

        if indexPath.row == 0 {
            myData[0] = myData.dropFirst().joined(separator: " : ")
            c.testLabel.text = myData[indexPath.row]
        } else {
            c.packageSizeTextField.text = myData[indexPath.row]
        }
        
        c.changeClosure = { [weak self, weak tableView] str, c in
            guard let self = self,
                  let tableView = tableView,
                  let pth = tableView.indexPath(for: c)
            else {
                return
            }
            // update our data
            self.myData[pth.row] = str
            // do something with the tableView
            //  such as reload the first row (row Zero)
            tableView.reloadRows(at: [IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)], with: .automatic)
        }
        return c
    }
}
```

---

**Edit 2**

There is a lot to discuss which goes beyond the scope of your question, but briefly...

First, **as a general rule** Classes should be as independent as possible.

- your Cell should only handle its elements
- your Data Source should only manage the data (and, of course, the necessary funds like returning cells, handling Edit commits, etc)
- your TableViewController should, as might be expected, *control the tableView*

If you are only manipulating the data and wanting to reload specific rows, it's not that big of a deal for your DataSource class to get a reference to the tableView.

But, what if you need to do more than that? For example:

[image]

You don't want your Cell or DataSource class to act on the button tap and do something like pushing a new controller onto a nav stack.

To use the protocol / delegate pattern, you can "pass a delegate reference" through the classes.

Here's an example (with just minimum code)...

Two protocols - one for text change, one for button tap:

```
protocol MyTextChangeDelegate: AnyObject {
    func cellTextChanged(_ cell: UITableViewCell)
}

protocol MyButtonTapDelegate: AnyObject {
    func cellButtonTapped(_ cell: UITableViewCell)
}
```

The controller class, which conforms to `MyButtonTapDelegate`:

```
class TheTableViewController: UITableViewController, MyButtonTapDelegate {
    
    lazy var myTableViewDataSource: TheTableViewDataSource = {
        TheTableViewDataSource()
    }()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // assign custom delegate to dataSource instance
        myTableViewDataSource.theButtonTapDelegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = myTableViewDataSource
    }

    // delegate func
    func cellButtonTapped(_ cell: UITableViewCell) {
        // do something
    }
    
}
```

The data source class, which conforms to `MyTextChangeDelegate` and has a reference to `MyButtonTapDelegate` to "pass to the cell":

```
final class TheTableViewDataSource: NSObject, UITableViewDataSource, MyTextChangeDelegate {
    
    weak var theButtonTapDelegate: MyButtonTapDelegate?
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let c = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! theCell
        // assign custom delegate to cell instance
        c.theTextChangeDelegate = self
        c.theButtonTapDelegate = self.theButtonTapDelegate
        return c
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 10
    }
    
    func cellTextChanged(_ cell: UITableViewCell) {
        // update the data
    }

}
```

and the Cell class, which will call the `MyTextChangeDelegate` (the data source class) on text change, and the `MyButtonTapDelegate` (the controller class) when the button is tapped:

```
final class theCell: UITableViewCell, UITextFieldDelegate {

    weak var theTextChangeDelegate: MyTextChangeDelegate?
    weak var theButtonTapDelegate: MyButtonTapDelegate?

    func textFieldDidChangeSelection(_ textField: UITextField) {
        theTextChangeDelegate?.cellTextChanged(self)
    }
    func buttonTapped() {
        theButtonTapDelegate?.cellButtonTapped(self)
    }

}
```

---

So, having said all that...

Speaking in the abstract can be difficult. For your **specific** implementation, you may be digging yourself into a hole.

You mention *"how to use a containerView / segmented control to switch between controllers"* ... It *might* be better to create a "data manager" class, rather than a "Data Source" class.

Also, with a little searching for `Swift Closure vs Delegate` you can find a lot of discussion stating that Closures are the preferred approach these days.

I put a project up on GitHub showing the two methods. The functionality is identical --- one approach uses Closures and the other uses Protocol/Delegate pattern. You can take a look and dig through the code (tried to keep it straight-forward) to see which would work better for you.

https://github.com/DonMag/DelegatesAndClosures

Comment: Don’t have the cell capture the index path. If you insert or delete cells before this one. It needs to reference the model for this cell, and then on change have the tvc look up the index path for the corresponding cell

Comment: @Shadowrun - good point... I edited my answer to reflect this.

Comment: @DonMag Thank you for your extremely in depth response as always. This is likely going to take me a few days to work through. I don't understand the syntax of closures very well, and I've got quite a few different cells to work with... Although the issue really seems to be my lack of understanding, and possibly desire to do too much in the dataSource. It seems that I may be better off leaving it all in the controller and figuring out how to use a containerView / segmented control to switch between controllers, as that seems to be my main objective for the separation in this instance.

Comment: @Shadowrun Is there a better way to determine the indexPath for the cell in it's delegate function? - The cells that capture the indexPath are all stationary and are not in a section where they can be moved/deleted. And it's only function is to be used for convenience purposes in a switch case so that I know I'm accessing the correct cell, for instances where there's multiple of the same cell type

Comment: @DonMag _One option is to have your MyTableViewController conform to your MyTableViewCellDelegate and then set the controller as the delegate in cellForRowAt in your dataSource class._ How exactly would this be done? Would I need to make something like `var controller: UITableViewController` inside the dataSoruce class?

Comment: If your table never changes then you can pass the index path to the cell - the key insight is whether or not an index path forms a 'stable identifier' that is valid beyond the lifetime of a reloadData or a begin/end updates. If you're handing the ip to the cell then that prolongs the lifetime of the index path and it may not be correct by the time the cell uses it. If a cell needs to know its index path then you look it up using `tableView.indexPath(for: cell)` but a cell is probably more interested in a model object than its index path

Comment: @StonedStudio - *"One option is to have your MyTableViewController conform to your MyTableViewCellDelegate and then set the controller as the delegate in cellForRowAt in your dataSource class."* ... take a look at **Edit 2** in my answer, as well as a quick project I put up on GitHub.

Comment: @DonMag Thank you. This is all very insightful. Thank you for uploading the project. I've gone ahead and cloned it and will be giving it a look. I believe you're absolutely correct that I've dug myself in a bit of a hole with this question, and it's entirely likely I asked the wrong question in regards to my actual problem. Please give me about a week to read and reread this all a few times, as well as really dive into xcode project. Thank you again!