# How do I access a UITextField in a xib from a tableview?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, xib

I am new to programing and Swift and trying to build a simple app that lets a user change a score and save that score to core data while also printing the score. How do I correctly access the gameCellScore textview inside of the xib so that I can save and print it? I tried using didSelectRowAt but nothing happens when I click on the textview and it crashes when I select the row.

Core data has an entity called Players and two attributes called playerName and round1.

Viewcontroller code

```
@IBOutlet weak var gamePlayers: UITableView!


let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
var playerArray = [Player]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    let nib = UINib(nibName: "GameTableViewCell", bundle: nil)
    gamePlayers.register(nib, forCellReuseIdentifier: "GameTableViewCell")
    
    gamePlayers.delegate = self
    gamePlayers.dataSource = self
    
    let newPlayer1 = Player(context: context)
    newPlayer1.playerName = "Player 1"
    newPlayer1.round1 = 1
    playerArray.append(newPlayer1)
    
    let newPlayer2 = Player(context: context)
    newPlayer2.playerName = "Player 2"
    newPlayer2.round1 = 2
    playerArray.append(newPlayer2)
    
    saveItems()
    loadPlayers()
   
    self.gamePlayers.reloadData()
    
    
}

func saveItems(){
    do{
        try context.save()
    }catch{
        print("Error saving")
    }
}

func loadPlayers(){
    let request : NSFetchRequest<Player> = Player.fetchRequest()
    do{
       playerArray = try context.fetch(request)
    } catch{
        print("Error fetching")
    }
}
```

extension ViewController: UITableViewDataSource{

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return playerArray.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "GameTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! GameTableViewCell
    
    cell.gameCellLabel.text = playerArray[indexPath.row].playerName
    cell.gameCellScore.text = String(playerArray[indexPath.row].round1)
    
    return cell
    
}
```

extension ViewController: UITableViewDelegate{

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "GameTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! GameTableViewCell
    let changePlayer = cell.gameCellScore.text
    playerArray[indexPath.row].setValue(Any?(changePlayer!), forKey: "round1")
    saveItems()
    loadPlayers()

    self.gamePlayers.reloadData()
    print(playerArray[indexPath.row].setValue(Any?(changePlayer!), forKey: "round1"))
    
    
    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
    
}
```

xib code

class GameTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

```
@IBOutlet weak var gameCellLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var gameCellScore: UITextField!

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code
}

override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}
```

Comment: What are the error messages when you tap the textField and what for the row? Have you set the delegate functions for the textField?

Comment: You don't want to *"access a UITextField in a xib from a tableview"* -- you want to use either protocol/delegate pattern or a closure and have your cell *inform your controller* when changes have been made. See this for starters:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/68090850/6257435

Comment: Thank you, DonMag. I followed the steps in the link and made some adjustments. App works as expected now.